# Change C# project from .NetStandard 1.4 to 1.6

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-standard

I'm trying to change an existing project from .NetStandard 1.4 to 1.6 in order to upgrade some nuget packages that need the 1.6 version.

I can't see the .NetStandard v1.6 in the Targets available.

[image]

I'm using:

- Windows 7 - SP1
- Visual Studio - 2015 v14.0.25431.01  with Update 3

Q: How can I add the .NetStandard v.16 to the targets? A download is missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You might need to install the latest release if the option you're expecting isn't showing in the dialogs. But you always have the option to update the project files directly, but it may or may not be supported with what you currently have installed.

Comment: Recommend avoiding .NET Standard 1.5 and 1.6 if possible; they are the black sheep of .NET Standard as they are not forward compatible with the upcoming .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: @CoryNelson some nuget packages require 1.6, like Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core